# calculating the number of parameters of a GRU layer (Keras)

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, gated-recurrent-unit

Why the number of parameters of the GRU layer is 9600?

Shouldn't it be ((16+32)*32 + 32) * 3 * 2 = 9,408  ?

or, rearranging,

32*(16 + 32 + 1)*3*2 = 9408

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=4500, output_dim=16, input_length=200),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.GRU(32)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

[image]

Comment: Which TensorFlow version are you using? When I run the code on `1.14.0` I get 9408.

Comment: I am using 2.0. I get the expected results for LSTMs, but not for GRU

Comment: That's pretty interesting. I went through the TensorFlow source for 2.0 but still all the Cells I went through ended up adding up to 9408. But I'll look into this why this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The answer below helped me to figure it out, apparently, it is due to the parameter reset_after.  Depending on whether it is set to True or False, the model uses a different number of bias terms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key is that tensorflow will separate biases for input and recurrent kernels when the parameter `reset_after=True` in `GRUCell`. You can look at some of the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e706a0bf1f3c0c666d31d6935853cfbea7c2e64e/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1598) in `GRUCell` as follow:

```
if self.use_bias:
    if not self.reset_after:
        bias_shape = (3 * self.units,)
    else:
        # separate biases for input and recurrent kernels
        # Note: the shape is intentionally different from CuDNNGRU biases
        # `(2 * 3 * self.units,)`, so that we can distinguish the classes
        # when loading and converting saved weights.
        bias_shape = (2, 3 * self.units)
```

Taking the reset gate as an example, we generally see the following formulas.
[image]

But if we set `reset_after=True`, the actual formula is as follows:
[image]

As you can see,  the default parameter of [`GRU`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8e423e3d56390671f0d954c90f4fd163ab02a9c1/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent_v2.py#L147-L419) is `reset_after=True`  in `tensorflow2`. But the default parameter of `GRU` is `reset_after=False` in `tensorflow1.x`.

So the number of parameters of a `GRU` layer should be `((16+32)*32 + 32 + 32) * 3 * 2 = 9600` in `tensorflow2`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried both True and False for reset_after, it is exactly as you said. Do you know what is the point of adding two separate bias terms? model can always set b_combined = b_input + b_recurrent, so what is the point? ( as far as I understand the only way it can make any difference, is if the same biases are used somehere else in the model for calculations

Comment: @AbidOrucov As the code comment says that `we can distinguish the classes when loading and converting saved weights`. For example, we switch weights from just one layer and set to another layer.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. `b_input` and `b_recurrent` are just 1-D vectors, with the same dimension as `br`. You can just add the vectors, call the sum `br` and then the two formula's are exactly identical. In other words, out of these 9600 parameters, 3*64=192 are redundant.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out a little bit more about this, as an addition to the accepted answer. What Keras does in `GRUCell.call()` is:

[image]

[image]

With `reset_after=False` (default in TensorFlow 1):

[image]

With `reset_after=True` (default in TensorFlow 2):

[image]

After training with `reset_after=False`, `b_xh` equals `b_hz`, `b_xr` equals `b_hr`and `b_xh` equals `b_hh`, because (I assume) TensorFlow realizes that each of these pairs of vectors can be combined into one single parameter vector - just like the OP pointed out in a comment above. However, with `reset_after=True`, that's *not* the case for `b_xh` and `b_hh` - they can and will be different, so they can *not* be combined into one vector, and that's why the total parameter count is higher.